# Gnuplot: Add Empty Leading and Trailing Space to Plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I've got a plot on `gnuplot` like this:

[image: Plot Example.]

How do I add some empty space before the first point and after the last point (leading and trailing spaces)? The objective is to end up with a well readable plot without having points overlapping the left and right y axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know the x data range beforehand, you could try something like

```
set output dummy_output
plot 'data.dat'
set xr [GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN-0.5:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX+0.5]
set output real_output
replot
```